# Meaning of "count in"

Tags: meaning

- The German Fischer, the two Americans no longer **count in** the outcome of the race, the Hungarian alone is battling the three Japanese.

I happened to read this sentence while browsing web and wondered what that *count in* would mean. I looked up the dictionary, but it says *count in* only has meaning of including something in a count of something, which didn't quite explain why. I suppose the *count in* above kind of means "to consider"?

Comment: ***To count***:   7. (intr) to have value, importance, or influence http://www.thefreedictionary.com/count. No longer *count* in the outcome of the race.

Comment: @Josh61 Then, *count in* isn't a phrasal verb as a whole, but *count* is an intransitive and *in* is a preposition? I thought it was somehow a phrasal verb--or some idiom--because there are some dictionaries, including The free dictionary, saying *count in* works as an idiom. [http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+in)

Comment: As you can see in from your link and from the expression ***count me in***,  the meaning is different and unrelated to your sentence. In your sentence it is not a phrasal verb. – http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+me+in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They no longer **count** in the race

means

> They no longer **matter** in the race